# What do maximumCallsPerCallGroup mean in iOS Callkit?

Tags: ios, callkit

I already read the Apple documentation related to maximumCallsPerCallGroup and still do not understand what it means.

I am developing a VOIP app and have this property while create CXProviderConfiguration object.

Setting it to 1 or 2 does not seem to make any difference.
If I set it to 1, app can receive 2nd call even when user is already on a call.

I was trying to implement 2 ringing calls at the same time i.e. if a call is ringing, and at same time another call is received, user should be notified of both the calls and choose which call to pickup.

Here is the link I was referring to while implementing this.
[CallKit with two incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562630/callkit-with-two-incoming-calls)

Comment: `maximumCallsPerCallGroup` determines the number of parties that can be merged into a single conversation. `maximumCallGroups` is the number of separate conversations that can be in progress at any time. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxsetgroupcallaction